# I want to sent an audio file from my app via whatsapp but everytime I get an exception. What did I do wrong?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to sent an audio from my app via WhatsApp, but there is allways these Exception. All the files are in my assets folder.

This is my Code:

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Intent sendthis = new Intent();
    sendthis.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendthis.setType("audio/*");

    assetManager = context.getAssets();
    try {
        String[] audios = assetManager.list("audio_files");
        sendthis.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, audios[0]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendthis, "Sende Silo in die Welt..."));
    return true;
}
```

This is the Eception I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable  
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:957)  
        at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:8576)  
        at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:11632)  
        at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:11612)  
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1710)  
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5252)  
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)  
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5203)  
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)  
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5581)  
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5549)  
        at com.example.myapp.MainActivity$2.onLongClick(MainActivity.java:62)  
        at android.view.View.performLongClickInternal(View.java:7959)  
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:7909)  
        at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:13546)  
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:7927)  
        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:29320)  
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)  
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)  
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)  
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8125)  
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)  
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard.

Second, `EXTRA_STREAM` for `ACTION_SEND` takes an `ArrayList` of `Uri` values, such as those from `FileProvider`. You are passing an `Array` of `String`.

Comment: try {  
     String[] audios = assetManager.list("audio_files");  
     ArrayList<URI> audiofiles = new ArrayList<>();  

     for(String audio: audios){  
         audiofiles.add(new URI(audio));  
     }  

     sendthis.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, audiofiles.get(0));  } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
 }    Changed it but still don't work

Comment: @FrankGross: First, `URI` and `Uri` are not the same thing. Second, those are invalid `URI` (or `Uri`) values. You cannot directly create a `Uri` for an asset that other apps can use. The simplest solution is for you to copy the assets to files (e.g., into `getCacheDir()`), then use `FileProvider` to create a `Uri` for each.